# Struts <logic:notEmpty> not working or bean property not being written properly to JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, struts, struts-tags

I'm beginning on bug fixes for a program with which I have little familiarity. I've changed a section of code on one of the JSPs. I need it to print names with either of the two following formats (depending on whether or not the middle name property exists):

> LastName, FirstName M.
>
> LastName, FirstName

I believe my code should print the middle initial and the period if and only if that property exists, but for each name in the list, it prints:

> LastName, FirstName .

It prints either no middle initial or a middle initial that is an empty string, followed by the period.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
<html:link styleClass="recordLink" action="/secure/admin/users?actionMethod=details" paramId="userId" paramName="users" paramProperty="userId">
    <bean:write name="users" property="lastName"/>,
    <bean:write name="users" property="firstName"/>
    <logic:notEmpty name="users" property="middleName">
        <bean:write name="users" property="middleName"/>.
    </logic:notEmpty>
</html:link>
```

Why is the `<logic:notEmpty>` tag not working? Could the `middleName` property be determined to be non-empty if the property doesn't exist? Is there something wrong with my syntax?

I've also tried to use JSTL tags, but I could not get it working in OC4J (Error: "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" is not a registered TLD namespace.)

Comment: Syntax looks fine. What happen if you delete the notEmpty condition? It prints any middleName?

Comment: It prints the same thing. It's like middle name is empty or null, but struts doesn't think it is.

Comment: I even threw a `<logic:present name="users" property="middleName">` around the `<logic:notEmpty>` tags to make sure that the `middleName` property even existed, and it still printed the same thing. If `middleName` is actually a `char` rather than a `String` could this be causing an issue?

Comment: Yes, it could be the problem. As I know struts try to get only `String` from the form.

Comment: It appears to be a String. Any other ideas?

Comment: My last bullet would be to check if you really have value for middleName in the form used by the `jsp`. For sure the problem isn't in the code you posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tag `logic:notEmpty` evaluates to true because your middle name string has spaces. You should get rid of spaces before returning it to the tag. Better do it in the form bean like

```
public String getMiddleName() { return middleName != null? middleName.trim(): middleName;}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like my middle name Strings have spaces. It prints an empty string or nothing at all.

Comment: Nothing at all it can't print, make sure you have a valid characters.

Comment: I think you're on to something. I placed quotes around the printing of the middle name (`"<bean:write name="users" property="middleName"/>".`) and it printed a space.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your `middleName` is empty string or has spaces. if so try using `logic:equal` to match and print some character instead of period, see what happens. If true, then trim the `middleName`, before sending it of to JSP.